# Ajax Response Error

Tags: categories, ajax, errors

I am going to be mad. I wasted 4 hours due this error but I can't solve it. When I want to create a category, wordpress give this error. [image]

I deleted each file in my theme, but I can't found where is the error. Also I create functions-admin.php. İf you have a idea for where is the error, just tell me I will care of thats file.

Also, it's working my free host and local host. But in the different servers I took this error.

Comment: Try deactivating all of your plugins and activating one of the default theme to see if the error is localized to one of those items.

Answer (score 0):

Double comment blocks makes me the same problem:

/*

... */

*/

Try to remove all commented blocks from your functions.php or included sub-functions. Clean your functions.php and add one by one function and you will find the issue. Third thing was PHP passing by reference, try to avoid it.